# How to fix window.CKFinder is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, ckfinder

I want to use `ckeditor 5` and `ckfinder` plugin to upload a file or image.
I setup `ckeditor` and plugins step by step with this [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html).
I can run `ckeditor` and see `ckfinder` icon on `ckeditor` but when click on the icon it will not open thel modal and the error is "window.CKFinder is undefined".
please help me to solve this problem.

```
<script src="../build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),{
    // Enable the CKFinder button in the toolbar.
    toolbar: [ 'ckfinder' ]
} )
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: 3 years later and the issue is still happening with clean default online built CKFinder instances. Nowhere a word from CKFinder about what a user should do to further implement CKFinder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and included the following script and now everything works fine.

```js
<script src="https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

[image: added script below ckeditor script]

you can also check the following link:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/86